# How to obtain Tukey Table in R?

Tags: r, tukey-hsd-test

The R provides a very confusing function for Tukey distribution.
The function `qtukey` needs a nonsensical parameter `nmeans` which forces the size of each treatment group to be the same.

My question is how can we obtain a Tukey upper quantile table(for studentized range distribution) table using qtukey function?(The table is like [Tukey Table](https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring98/sta110c/qtable.html))
In SAS, it provides a perfect solution of `prob('range',.,prob,df,v)`,should I type `qtukey(1-prob,(df+v)/v,df,nrange=v)` in R?

But when I type that, I get a wrong number for $q_{\nu,df,\alpha}$? I just do not understand why R provides such a obscure function.

Answer (score 11):

Here's part of the table you linked to:
[image]

The first few rows are obtained by:

```
> qtukey(p = 0.95, nmeans = 2:10, df = 5)
[1] 3.635351 4.601725 5.218325 5.673125 6.032903 6.329901 6.582301 6.801398
[9] 6.994698

> qtukey(p = 0.99, nmeans = 2:10, df = 5)
[1]  5.702311  6.975727  7.804156  8.421495  8.913107  9.320875  9.668681
[8]  9.971483 10.239281

> qtukey(p = 0.95, nmeans = 2:10, df = 6)
[1] 3.460456 4.339195 4.895599 5.304891 5.628353 5.895309 6.122202 6.319211
[9] 6.493085
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out. I think that R-help is misleading for the command qtukey.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to generate QTable into a data frame.
You can change the grid limits according to your needs.

```
QTable <- expand.grid(alpha=c(0.01,0.05),
                      groups=seq(2,10,1),
                      df=seq(2,120,1))

QTable$QVal=qtukey(1-QTable$alpha,QTable$groups,df=QTable$df)

  head(QTable)
  alpha groups df      QVal
  1  0.01      2  2 13.902105      
  2  0.05      2  2  6.079637
  3  0.01      3  2 19.015496
  4  0.05      3  2  8.330783
  5  0.01      4  2 22.563706
  6  0.05      4  2  9.799011
```

Answer (score 0):

For exaplanatory purpose, I tried to make up a function which provides full Tukey Table, see my comments inside. I still think that the R-help is misleading in this case:

```
QTable<-function(dfrange=10,nurange=20,alpha=0.05,digs=3){

  ROWS<-dfrange
  COLS<-nurange
  tabl<-matrix(nrow=ROWS,ncol=COLS)
  for(a in 2:COLS){
    tabl[1,a]=a
  }
  for(b in 2:ROWS){
    tabl[b,1]=b
  }

  for(i in 2:ROWS){
    for(j in 2:COLS){
      tabl[i,j]<-qtukey(alpha,j,i,nranges=1,lower.tail=FALSE)
      #R has a wrong description for the parameter 'nmeans',
      #To get a correct result, always set 'nranges'=1, from the description       #of R:
      #i=n-nu;j=nu->n=i+j;nu=j->number of groups nu=j;
      #Each group has n/nu elements, which is (i+j)/j
      #The above interpretation is wrong, the parameter 'nmeans' 
      #should be regarded as number of groups when 'nranges'=1
      tabl[i,j]<-round(tabl[i,j],digs)
    }
  }
  tmp<-as.data.frame(tabl)
  colnames(tmp)<-as.character(tmp[1,])
  tmp<-tmp[-1,]
  rownames(tmp)<-as.character(tmp[,1])
  tmp<-tmp[,-1]
  message("significant level=",alpha)
  message("nu=1:",nurange,", df=1:",dfrange)
  message("Rows are the value sequence of df;Columns are the nu sequence.")
  print(tmp)
}
QTable(dfrange=20,nurange=8,alpha=0.01)
```